# jquery selector sometimes is unresponsive

Tags: jquery

```
$('a').bind('click',function(e){
alert("hi");
});
```

with some sites, it fails. that is until i reload it again, it works.

why does this seem to happen ?

Comment: I don't see how that will fail. probably caching problems with the jquery.js file?

Comment: please paste a demo of it not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may also want to check out the .live keyword as in

```
$("a").live("click", function
```

as this will bind the click event even if you add the control after a partial postback.

Answer (score 3):

Is it in `$(document).ready(function() {` so that it waits till the page is fully loaded?